# What constitutes a "deep space" mission in Starfleet, and how were ships provisioned to complete them?

Tags: star-trek

There are several references to ships going on "deep space" missions intentionally (that is, not like Voyager did). If I recall correctly, Harry Kim, in Voyager's Endgame originaly timeline, wasn't around for Chakotay's funeral because he was in "deep space".

What constitutes a deep space mission, and how were ships prepared for going on them that would be different from a mission like that of the Enterprise-D, which was supported partially by starbases?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deep Space is basically Federation-speak for "*areas that we haven't tamed'*", where your ship (or space station) is the only piece of Federation real estate in the area.

> **BASHIR:** *I didn't want some cushy job or a research grant. I wanted this. The farthest reaches of the galaxy. One of the most remote outposts available. This is where the adventure is. This is where heroes are made. Right here, in the wilderness.*
>
> **KIRA:** *This wilderness is my home.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Emissary](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/401.htm)</sup></sub>

The presence of Federation-friendly outposts and starbases means that you're *not* in deep space.

> Most colonies start small, after space has been secured and studded with outposts. That’s why the military goes first into the wilderness and establishes forts. **These colonists don’t have any idea what unoutposted deep space is like. They think they’re rowing across a nice calm pond. The area they want to settle hasn’t even been thoroughly scouted.** Just because there’s been no sign of trouble doesn’t mean there isn’t any trouble.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: New Earth - *Wagon Train to the Stars*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Wagon_Train_to_the_Stars)</sup></sub>

It follows that you need to have sufficient provisions to go where you're going, and to be self-sustaining until you get back. The Constitution-Class Enterprise, for example, had a five-year mission where they basically mooched around *just outside* Federation space, met a bunch of new aliens and then came back to Federation starbases whenever they needed to resupply.

Comment: "The presence of Federation-friendly outposts and starbases means that you're not in deep space."  Deep Space 9 is a Federation outpost, and is presumably considered to be in deep space.  If DS9 doesn't count because it was obtained from the Cardassians, the implied existence of DS1-8 could fill in.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis - DS9 is on the edge of deep space, e.g. the frontier beyond which there are no more Federation starbases

Comment: Well maybe early on Bajor was intended to be the "farthest reaches of the galaxy" but in reality it is on the border of klingon space.  And close enough that the Romulans can easily visit.  So if it's anything it's the border of the original series superpowers from a century ago.  The question is what's deep space - not why some space stations get designated that.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Klingon Space isn't Federation space. It's largely unexplored *by Federation people*. The people who live there don't count

Comment: @Valorum I guess "Last stop before entering deep space 9" was a little long for a title, although I'm sure they could have gotten through it during the ridiculously long intro.

Comment: It may be notable that Bajor is generally considered a mere 52 light years from Earth.  The only thing making that deep is a border.  (Earth seems extremely close to 2 hostile empires as the Romulans can't be far either) Analogously Washington D.C. to Richmond is only 100miles.  It's in the Confederacy but it's not the deep south.  And the terrain kept the warvout of Washington.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis technically, DS9 is a Bajoran starbase, but it does have a Federation garrison assigned to it (with permission from the Bajorans) that is pretty much permanent except for occasional evacuations.

Comment: DS9 is a Space Western, they're in a frontier town, complete with bar. To expand on @lucasbachmann, look at the [US map in 1860](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_frontier#/media/File:United_States_1859-1860.png). You got a gold rush on one side, civilization on the other, the wild west with frontier towns in the middle, and a [new railroad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_transcontinental_railroad) right through the middle. Draw your analogies.

Answer (score 3):

From TNG Technical Manual for Galaxy Class

> **"MISSION**
>
> • Ability to operate independent of starbase refurbishment for extended periods. Independent exploration mode capability of seven Standard years at nominal Warp 6 velocity
> for docked configuration. Ability to execute deep-space
> exploration missions including charting and mapping."

From transcript at http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/622.htm
VOYAGER S6E24 Life Line

> ADMIRAL HAYES [on monitor]: Hello, Captain. I hope this message finds you well. From what I understand, it has not been easy, but I want you to know that a lot of people here are very proud of what you've accomplished. I also want to assure you that we have not given up finding a way to get you home. We've redirected two deep space vessels toward your position. If all goes well, they could rendezvous with you in the next five to six years.

Quoting the math here

[https://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/~jansen/st/voyager/distance.html](https://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/%7Ejansen/st/voyager/distance.html).

> "At the end of Dark Frontier (5.8) the transwarp coil recovered from a Borg ship allowed a trip of 20000 lightyears or approximately 15 years closer to home, before the device burned out.
>
> The USS Voyager is now still facing a journey of approx. 45 years."

As far as the "deep space" mission of those two ships.  We don't know when they started.  We can probably assume they'll be going faster than what Voyager is doing for safety.  As many of us calculated Warp 9.7 for a couple of years can get you 70,000 light years.

So if Voyager and the deep space mission ships are roughly 6 years away from each other that's roughly 15,000 light years using their combined velocities.

Or the two ships were roughly 30,000 light years away from earth already.  Basically I'd assume that's way past the opposite side of of Klingon space.

My opinion- I'd estimate anything past 10,000 light years of your own space is considered deep.  Or maybe anything past a 5 year mission.

It may also be worth noting that the normal use of "deep space" in the TNG Technical Manual is what I'd regard as normal Star Trek missions and normal ranges.  The reference to deep space missions being able to intercept Voyager is clearly what the OP and I would regard as "deep".  Deep enough maybe they aren't expected to return but just set up a far out colony and no one will miss them back home - that kind of deep.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that "uncharted space" - space not in the Federation database - is [deep space](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Space#Deep_space).

Comment: Slightly further down the page "*It is never mentioned what the exact definition of "deep space"*"